# It keeps showing the error function does not exists

Tags: mysql

[Table WORKER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ4c6.png)

[Table PAYLEVEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fboNO.png)

I need the mysql Query:
To display the PLEVEL and number of workers in that PLEVEL whose pay is greater than 15000

I tried these

```
mysql> SELECT WORKER.count(PLEVEL), PAY 
        FROM WORKER 
            JOIN PAYLEVEL ON WORKER.PLEVEL=PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL 
        where pay >= 15000;
```

> ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION worker.count does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Also

```
mysql> SELECT PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL,count(PLEVEL), PAY 
        FROM WORKER 
            JOIN PAYLEVEL ON WORKER.PLEVEL=PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL 
        where pay >= 15000;
```

> ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'PLEVEL' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: `SELECT WORKER.PLEVEL, COUNT(WORKER.PLEVEL), PAY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count is not a function of the table  name so you dont need prefix the function count with the table name,  eventually you need the table name inside the count fuction for the column name argument

```
 SELECT count(worker.PLEVEL), PAY 
    FROM WORKER 
        JOIN PAYLEVEL ON WORKER.PLEVEL=PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL 
    where pay >= 15000
 GROUP BY PAY;
```

and for aggregated  function you need  group by too

if you need  aggrgation also for plevel then

```
SELECT count(worker.PLEVEL), PAY, PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL 
    FROM WORKER 
        JOIN PAYLEVEL ON WORKER.PLEVEL=PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL 
    where pay >= 15000
 GROUP BY PAY, PAYLEVEL.PLEVEL ;
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot.. I wanna clear one thing... why did we write group by PAY not group by PLEVEL.

Comment: i.m not in  your data so i don't know your goal  ..anyway  the sql sintax require the mention in order by clause  of the  not aggreated  column  present in  select clause .. .your PLEVEL seems just a joining clause not related  to the aggregation  .. .. if you need  the PLEVEL aggregation subtotal you can add  also this column to the select and the group  by clause .